# Matplotlib annotation detailed documentation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am sorry but I really tried to find the following in the documentation:

What does armA, armB, angleA, anngleB each mean in the plt.annotate? For example, in:

```
ax.annotate('arc', xy=(1.5, -1),  xycoords='data',
            xytext=(-40, -30), textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle=
            "arc,angleA=0,armA=20,angleB=-90,armB=15,rad=7"),)
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: look for them [here](http://matplotlib.org/Matplotlib.pdf)
and the answer is also [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/artist_api.html)

Comment: @adrin The artists link does contain what I wanted! Thank you so much. Would you like to make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those parameters are to initialize the `ConnectionStyle.Arc` class. As you can see in detail [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/artist_api.html).

> class ConnectionStyle.Arc(angleA=0, angleB=0, armA=None, armB=None,
>   rad=0.0)
>
> Bases: matplotlib.patches._Base
>
> Creates a picewise continuous quadratic bezier path between two
>   points. The path can have two passing-through points, a point placed
>   at the distance of armA and angle of angleA from point A, another
>   point with respect to point B. The edges are rounded with rad.
>
> angleA : starting angle of the path
>
> angleB : ending angle of the path
>
> armA : length of the starting arm
>
> armB : length of the ending arm
>
> rad : rounding radius of the edges
>
> connect(posA, posB)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at the given locations is very sparse, and nowhere are the angles angleA, angleB, armA, armB defined, so it is very much a matter of trial-and-error.

I wrote a script that provides radio buttons to select between ConnectionStyle **angle3**, **arc3**, **angle**, and **arc**, and then provided sliders to enter **angleA**, **armA**, **angleB**, **armB**, **rad**. I discovered that each ConnectionStyle accepts only its own set of arguments, there is an error if, for example, you provide a radius (rad) to angle3, or an angleA to arc3, etc. In other words you need this kind of if statement to pass only the expected arguments for the different connection types:

```
if connStyle == 'angle3':
    connstyle="angle3,angleA=%4.2f,angleB=%4.2f"%(angleA,angleB)
elif connStyle == 'arc3':
    connstyle="arc3,rad=%4.2f"%(radius)
elif connStyle == 'angle':
    connstyle="angle,angleA=%4.2f,angleB=%4.2f,rad=%4.2f"%(angleA,angleB,radius*10.)
elif connStyle == 'arc':
    connstyle="arc,angleA=%4.2f,angleB=%4.2f,armA=%4.2d,armB=%4.2f,rad=%4.2f"%(angleA,angleB,armA,armB,radius)
```

The angles angleA and angleB seem to be oriented with 0 degrees pointing left, 90 degrees pointing downward, i.e. leftward-oriented counter-clockwise-positive angle measured in degrees. But the curve does some really strange stuff outside a central range.

Here is the whole script so you can play around with it yourself. This stuff is almost totally undocumented and a little peculiar.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

# Global variables
angleA = 90.0
armA = 1.0
angleB = 0.0
armB = 1.0
connStyle = 'angle3'
# connStyle = 'arc3'
# connStyle = 'angle'
# connStyle = 'arc'
radius=0.1


plt.close('all')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_axes([.25,.4,.7,.5])
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 10])

axcolor = 'w'
axAngleA = plt.axes([0.25, 0.25,   0.65, 0.03],  axisbg=axcolor)
axArmA   = plt.axes([0.25, 0.2,  0.65, 0.03],  axisbg=axcolor)
axAngleB = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15,   0.65, 0.03],  axisbg=axcolor)
axArmB   = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1,  0.65, 0.03],  axisbg=axcolor)
axRadius = plt.axes([0.25, 0.05,  0.65, 0.03],  axisbg=axcolor)

SlAngleA = Slider(axAngleA, 'AngleA', -180.0, 180.0, valinit=angleA)
SlArmA   = Slider(axArmA,   'ArmA', -10., 10., valinit=armA)
SlAngleB = Slider(axAngleB, 'AngleB', -180.0, 180.0, valinit=angleB)
SlArmB   = Slider(axArmB,   'ArmB', -10., 10., valinit=armB)
SlRadius = Slider(axRadius, 'Rad', -10., 10., valinit=radius)

# Display function
def display(connstyle):
    ax.cla()
    plt.annotate("ArrowTest",
                 xytext=(8, 8),
                 xy=(2,2),
                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                                 connectionstyle=connstyle))

    # plt.show()
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


# Update function
def update(val):
    global angleA, angleB, armA, armB, connStyle, radius
    angleA = SlAngleA.val
    armA   = SlArmA.val
    angleB = SlAngleB.val
    armB   = SlArmB.val
    radius = SlRadius.val

    if connStyle == 'angle3':
        connstyle="angle3,angleA=%4.2f,angleB=%4.2f"%(angleA,angleB)
    elif connStyle == 'arc3':
        connstyle="arc3,rad=%4.2f"%(radius)
    elif connStyle == 'angle':
        connstyle="angle,angleA=%4.2f,angleB=%4.2f,rad=%4.2f"%(angleA,angleB,radius*10.)
    elif connStyle == 'arc':
        connstyle="arc,angleA=%4.2f,angleB=%4.2f,armA=%4.2d,armB=%4.2f,rad=%4.2f"%(angleA,angleB,armA,armB,radius)

    # print 'connstyle = "%s"'%connstyle    

    display(connstyle)

SlAngleA.on_changed(update)
SlArmA.on_changed(update)
SlAngleB.on_changed(update)
SlArmB.on_changed(update)
SlRadius.on_changed(update)

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.005, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')
def reset(event):
    SlangleA.reset()
    SlangleB.reset()
    SlRad.reset()
    ax.cla()
button.on_clicked(reset)

rax = plt.axes([0.025, 0.5, 0.15, 0.15], axisbg=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('angle3', 'arc3', 'angle', 'arc'), active=0)
def connstylefunc(label):
    global connStyle
    connStyle = label
    # print "Switch connstyle to %s"%connStyle
    display(connStyle)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
radio.on_clicked(connstylefunc)

# Plot first time
plt.sca(ax)
display("angle3,angleA=%4.2f,angleB=%4.2f"%(angleA,angleB))

plt.show()
figmgr=plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figmgr.canvas.manager.window.raise_()
geom=figmgr.window.geometry()
x,y,dx,dy=geom.getRect()
figmgr.window.setGeometry(10,10,dx,dy)
```

I had a screenshot of the script in action, but I guess I don't have enough reputation points to post it.